How to adjust "watershed" on medical image?
I now have a predicted mask and the original image, and I want to separate the two nuclei that are connected together.
But I can't get it out of my head with any adjustments, so what should I do to make it better?
Here is my program code:
from scipy import ndimage as ndi
from skimage.feature import peak_local_max
from skimage.segmentation import watershed as wts

def watershed(mask_map, label_map=None):
    ######  distanceTransform
    dis = cv2.distanceTransform(mask_map, distanceType=cv2.DIST_L2, maskSize=5)
    dis = cv2.normalize(dis, None, 255,0, cv2.NORM_MINMAX, cv2.CV_8UC1)
    
    ######  get label
    mask_ski = opencv2skimage(mask_map)
    dis_ski = opencv2skimage(dis)
    if label_map is None:###### auto label
        mask_ski_int = mask_ski.astype(np.int32)  # Ensure the mask is in integer format

        label_map = peak_local_max(dis_ski, exclude_border=0, indices=False, 
                           footprint=np.ones((17, 17)), labels=mask_ski_int) #(11, 11)
                                
    markers_map, num_features = ndi.label(label_map, structure=np.ones((3,3))) #np.ones((3,3))
    if num_features > 1:
        result = wts(-dis_ski, markers_map, mask=mask_ski, watershed_line=True)
        ######  clear bound
        mask_map[result==0] = 0

    return mask_map

from scipy.ndimage import label as lb, generate_binary_structure
from skimage.morphology import binary_dilation, disk

def target_watershed(full_shape, contour, label_map=None,color='blue'):
    '''auto-watershed target contour in full_shape and return contours'''
    ####### build mask by full_shape and contour
    if len(full_shape) > 2:
        full_shape = full_shape[:2]
    mask = np.zeros(full_shape, dtype=np.uint8)
    cv2.drawContours(mask , [contour], -1 , (255) , thickness=-1)
    # mask = cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
    # print(mask.shape)
    
    cut_mask = watershed(mask, None) #label_map
    # cut_mask = apply_watershed(mask=mask)
    ####### get each region contour
    cut_contours=[]
    # cut_mask = cv2.cvtColor(cut_mask, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cut_contours, _ = cv2.findContours(cut_mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    # cv2.drawContours(label_map , [cut_contours], -1 , (255) , thickness=-1)
    num_label, label =cv2.connectedComponents(cut_mask, connectivity=4)
    for n in range(1, num_label, 1):
        cnts, _ = cv2.findContours((label==n).astype(np.uint8)
                                , cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL
                                , cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
        cut_contours += cnts
    if color == 'blue':
        cv2.drawContours(label_map, cut_contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
    else:
        cv2.drawContours(label_map, cut_contours, -1, (0, 0, 255), 2)
    return cut_contours,label_map


When I adjust the "footprint" I get a full cut in half, and I get a lot of lines with this loop.
for n in range(1, num_label, 1):
        cnts, _ = cv2.findContours((label==n).astype(np.uint8)
                                , cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL
                                , cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
        cut_contours += cnts

I've tried it too. If it's a more rounded pellet I skip it.
def calculate_circularity(contour):
    area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
    perimeter = cv2.arcLength(contour, True)
    circularity = 4 * np.pi * area / (perimeter ** 2)
    return circularity

I'd like to ask for your advice on how to do this.

Please provide an example image that makes it possible to reproduce your proplem!
